# How do I change my CELERY_BROKER_URL in an already daemonized Celery process?

Tags: django, ubuntu, celery, supervisord

I'm daemonizing my Celery worker using Supervisord. The issue is I had a typo in my `CELERY_BROKER_URL` and the worker is not properly connecting to RabbitMQ.

When I run `celery -A mysite report` it shows the old environment variable.

My `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf` file does not include the environment variables:

```
[program:celery]
command=/webapps/mysite/scripts/celery/celery_start

autostart=true
autorestart=true

user=myuser

stdout_logfile=/webapps/mysite/logs/celery.log
redirect_stderr = true
```

The environment variables are picked up via my virtual environment in the `celery_start` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

DJANGODIR=/webapps/mysite/mysite

# Activate the virtual environment.
cd $DJANGODIR
. /webapps/mysite/bin/activate
. /webapps/mysite/bin/postactivate

# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves
# (do not use --daemon).
exec celery -A mysite worker -E -l info --concurrency=2
```

When I check the `CELERY_BROKER_URL` environment variable after activating the environment it is correct. I've tried `supervisorctl restart celery` which doesn't pick up the new environment variable (`celery -A mysite report` shows the old `CELERY_BROKER_URL`). I've tried `supervisorctl shutdown` and then `supervisord` which also won't pick up the new environment variable.

When I run `ps aux | grep 'celery worker'` I don't see anything, presumably because Celery is daemonized by Supervisor, so I'm not sure of a way to completely destroy the current Celery process.

No matter what, it feels like Celery is not picking up the new environment variable. How could I make this happen?

[EDIT]
My Celery settings in `settings.py` are as follows:

```
# Celery settings.
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get(
    'BROKER_URL', 'amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1//')
CELERY_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 60
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
```

And my `mysite/celery.py` file is:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings.local')

APP = Celery('mysite')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
APP.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
APP.autodiscover_tasks()


@APP.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Comment: Are we sure celery is picking up the URL from the environment variable and not django settings?  Can you please post your mysite/celery.py file for us to confirm?

Comment: @2ps see my `settings.py` file and my `mysite/celery.py` file. Thank you for taking a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I was using a password for my broker that for some reason contained an invalid character.

The password was `#qahrKscbW#3!HkMJg#jFcyaOR7HtK%j08Jt$yY2`.

What was happening was that my broker_url was invalid, and so it was defaulting back to `ampq://guest:password` instead of `ampq://myuser:#qahrKscbW#3!HkMJg#jFcyaOR7HtK%j08Jt$yY2@localhost/mysite`.

I changed the password to only use alphanumeric characters and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding the password eliminates issues related to special characters, proving a more secure and efficient alternative:

```python
import urllib.parse

password = ...  # your connection password (as str)
encoded_password = urllib.parse.quote_plus(password)
```

Now you may utilize `encoded_password` in your connection string instead of the plain password.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#escaping-special-characters-such-as-signs-in-passwords